# Prisma - How to reference SQL view in schema

Tags: postgresql, prisma, supabase

I am designing a database schema for a multi-tenant project where a single user might have multiple "profiles", one for different tenants.  I am using Supabase to provide a Postgres database along with some of their other BaaS features and hoping to use Prisma to help me manage the schema, relations, and migrations.

Supabase provides their own auth service, leveraging their `auth.users` table (in the `auth` schema).  I want/need my `public.profiles` table to have a 1-n relation with `auth.users` so I can link my user to all of their profiles.

Is there a way I can define this in my `schema.prisma` file?  I have tried manually creating a `VIEW` in the database and then defining a model for it, but when I try to apply my other Prisma schema changes (`npx prisma db push` or `npx prisma db migrate dev`) I get an error that the view/model already exists.

When database is initialized, I create the `Auth` SQL view in the public schema.

```sql
CREATE VIEW "Auth" AS SELECT id, email, role, created_at, updated_at, invited_at from auth.users;
```

Then in my Prisma schema I replicate the model.  This seems to be the approach if you are using introspection, but I want Prisma to manage the schema, not the other way around.

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

// SQL view in public schema of Supabase "auth.users" table
model Auth {
  id            Int         @unique
  email         String
  role          String
  createdAt     DateTime    @map("created_at")
  updatedAt     DateTime    @map("updated_at")
  invitedAt     DateTime    @map("invited_at")
  profiles      Profile[]
}

model Profile {
  id            Int         @id @default(autoincrement())

  // This relation should reference the "auth.users" table
  user          Auth        @relation(fields: [uid], references: [id])
  uid           Int

  client        Client      @relation(fields: [clientId], references: [id])
  clientId      Int
  firstName     String
  lastName      String
}

model Client {
  id            Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt     DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime    @default(now())
  name          String
  type          String
  preferences   Json
  profiles      Profile[]
}
```

Essentially, I need to know how I can create a relation to some portion of the schema that Prisma does not control.  Can I define a reference-only model? Or a model that should be ignored during `push` or `migrate` operations?  Can I define an explicit table name in the model relation definition?

There is [this issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/678) that talks about adding more support for views, but it's unclear if/when anything will happen.  I'm wondering if anyone has a different solution.  If this won't work I may just need to look into using something like NextAuth so I can fully manage the auth schema, but I'd prefer not to rebuild an auth system if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a public.users table via Prisma and add a Postgres trigger to duplicate the auth.users data to your public schema anytime a user signs up:

```sql
/**
* This trigger automatically creates a user entry when a new user signs up via Supabase Auth.
*/ 
create function public.handle_new_user() 
returns trigger as $$
begin
  insert into public.users (id, full_name, avatar_url)
  values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'avatar_url');
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

Does that approach work for you?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using a trigger to duplicate data, simply because I'm less familiar with them in Postgres, but this approach seems like it would work for my needs.  Can/should I use Prisma migrations along with Supabase migrations at the same time to make sure these types of triggers get initialized properly?  It seems dubious to use two different migration tools!